# Improve the search functionality

Tags: java, sql, performance, jsp, search

How can I improve the search functionality.? I have written some codes to search for something.The search was taking too much time. And the code snippets here,

I am pulling the data from the database using this method.,

```
   OracleConnection connection = null;
   OraclePreparedStatement ptmst = null;
   OracleResultSet rs = null;
   OracleCallableStatement cstmt = null;
   StringBuffer strBfr = new StringBuffer();
   ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();
    try
    {     
      connection = (OracleConnection) TransactionScope.getConnection();
      strBfr.append("select distinct .......... ");  
      ptmst = (OraclePreparedStatement)connection.prepareStatement(strBfr.toString());    
      rs = (OracleResultSet)ptmst.executeQuery();           
      while (rs.next()) 
                {               
                HashMap hashItems = new HashMap();
                hashItems.put("first",rs.getString(1));
                hashItems.put("second",rs.getString(2));    
                myList.add(hashItems);
                }       

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        }
    finally {

            try {
                if (ptmst != null) {
                    ptmst.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            try {
                if (connection != null) {
                    TransactionScope.releaseConnection(connection);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
        return myList;
```

In my jsp:

```
 ArrayList getValues = new ArrayList();     
    getValues = //calling Method here.
    for(int i=0; i < getValues.size();i++)  
    {
    HashMap quoteSrch=(HashMap)allPOV.get(i);                        
    first = (String)quoteSrch.get("first");
    second = (String)quoteSrch.get("second");
    }
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(mtl.segment1),
  mtl.description ,
  mtl.inventory_item_id ,
  mtl.attribute16
FROM mtl_system_items_b mtl,
  mtl_system_items_tl k
WHERE 1                           =1
AND mtl.organization_id           = ?
AND k.inventory_item_id           = mtl.inventory_item_id
AND NVL(orderable_on_web_flag,'N')= 'Y'
AND NVL(web_status,'UNPUBLISHED') = 'PUBLISHED'
AND mtl.SEGMENT1 LIKE ?  --Here is the search term
```

Comment: One thing you could do is use a stored procedure in the database, so it can optimize and store the best way to carry it out instead of needing to recompute it every single time.

Comment: @Patashu, that's what a prepared statement does as well. is it the query that is taking long? If so, posting the code won't help and you'd need to see if the query can be optimized, e.g. check for missing indexes, etc.

Comment: Verify that `TransactionScope.getConnection();` is not creating connection on every call as it will slow down the method performance. If it is reusing a connection/pool then post the SQL so you can ask suggestion to refactor/improve it

Comment: I think the query need to be optimized. As it takes time to fetch the results. I have edited the question with query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure organization_id , inventory_item_id and especially **SEGMENT1** is indexed in your table.

Your query is pretty standard , if that doesn't work then it seems like your DB server is responding slow which could be due to number of reasons like low space , low memory , slow disk/read etc.

You can then ask your DBA/Server admins to check that.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to find out the real problem

- Is it the DB query
- Is it the Network (is the App and the DB located on the same machine?)

Once you have identified that it is the DB query, then it becomes more of a DB question.

- How does the two tables look like?
- Any index used?
- How does the data look like (How many rows etc)

After you have analyzed this, you should be able to post the question differently and expect an answer. I am not a DB guy, but I am sure someone would be able to provide some pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Tunning has to be done:

1. Check `TransactionScope.getConnection();` is giving connection without any delay.
2. Instead of creating new `HashMap hashItems = new HashMap();` you can use

   ```
   while (rs.next()){
     myList.add(rs.getString(1) + "delimiter" + rs.getString(2)); 
   }
   ```

in jsp use

```
first = allPOV.get(i).split("delimter")[0];
second = allPOV.get(i).split("delimter")[1];
```

so that you can **reduce memory**.

1. If possible use limit in your query, and use index on **SEGMENT1** [link](http://www.rampant-books.com/t_oracle_sql_tuning_tips.htm).